# Cannot find jena.db package with maven

Tags: java, maven, jena

I have a little problem with jena. I want to use https://github.com/ldodds/slug in one of my project. This application comes without dependencies so I use Maven to gather what this app needs. Maven resolved everything except one package

```
import com.hp.hpl.jena.db.*;
```

I cannot resolve it with any of jena maven respositories. Do you know where I can find it? Maybe jena.db was available in older package but I cannot find any migration guide about this package.

If you are familiar with problem or know Jena structure well, please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The RDB storage layer (the package com.hp.hpl.jena.db) was removed from Jena a long time.  Presumably slug works with the version of in it's lib directory.

It would be better to use TDB or generalise and use SPARQL (query and update) so it will work with an external, standard triple store (like Jena Fuseki -- there are many to choose from).  It will need changes to slug.

Comment: I will write Fuseki handler then, thanks. For now, I have just deleted DB from slug and use FileStorage rather than Database. Slug compiles without a problem. Thanks for info.